# Outbound mail config in civicrm.settings.php?

Tags: email

Is it possible to store the outbound mail settings in civicrm.settings.php?
SMTP server IP address, port, user...

Comment: If you can provide a few more details on why you want to do this, I might be able to be of more help and expand on my answer below.

Comment: The reason is that depending on where the site is deployed (live, staging, local machine) other outbound mail settings should be defined.

Comment: Another approach is to use the API to edit the settings as part of a clone to staging / local machine script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In civicrm.settings.php

global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['Mailing Preferences']['mailing_backend'] = [
 'outBound_option' => 0,
 'smtpServer' => 'localhost',
 'smtpPort' => 1025,
 'smtpAuth' => false
];

Answer (score 0):

No. Outbound mail settings are typically configured here: civicrm/admin/setting/smtp. They can't be overridden in civicrm.settings.php apart from to disable them completely by defining CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG, e.g.

```
define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG', '/var/log/civicrm_mail');
```

or

```
define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG', '/dev/null');
```

If you aren't interested in them.